# Where are save games located?

Tags: besiege

Where are the save games for Besiege? I would like to backup my saves, but I don't know where they are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saved files are stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Besiege\Besiege_Data

Your unlocked levels are stored in CompletedLevels but the individual machine and stats are in the Levelx files. Saved machines can be found in the SavedMachines folder.